# Having Trouble Combining Parameters And Separate Function Inside A Function

Tags: javascript, function

I can't figure out how to call parameters in a function and another function at the same time. I can call a function from a different function without any problems, but adding additional parameters is where I get lost.

Here's what I've tried so far:
https://jsfiddle.net/Realto619/7fgt2za2/1/

```
var G = [3, 2, 0, 0, 3, 3];
var Gm = [33, 3, 3, 33, 33, 33];
var Em = [0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0];

function setChord(str6, str5, str4, str3, str2, str1) { 
  var domPath = 'http://chords.netcentrx.net/img/halfsize/f';
  var setFrets =  ' <div class="fretboard">\n' +
  '  <img class="str6" src="' + domPath + str6 + '.png" />\n' +
  '  <img class="str5" src="' + domPath + str5 + '.png" />\n' +
  '  <img class="str4" src="' + domPath + str4 + '.png" />\n' +
  '  <img class="str3" src="' + domPath + str3 + '.png" />\n' +
  '  <img class="str2" src="' + domPath + str2 + '.png" />\n' +
  '  <img class="str1" src="' + domPath + str1 + '.png" />\n' +
  ' </div>\n'; 
  return setFrets;              
}

function testChord(chordName)    {
  var myObject = setChord.apply(myObject, chordName);  
  $('body').append(myObject);  
}

testChord(Gm);
testChord(G);

// it works up thru here, but then fails miserably...

function testChord2(divID, chordDesc, chordName)    {
  var setChordDiv = '<div class="chord" id="' + divID + '">\n' +
  ' <div class="chord">\n' +
  '  <div class="chordName">' + chordDesc + '</div>';
  return setChordDiv;                  
  var myObject = setChord.apply(myObject, chordName);  
  var setChordDiv2 = '   </div>'+
  ' </div>'+
  '</div>';
  return setChordDiv2;                  
  $('body').append(setChordDiv+myObject+setChordDiv2);  
}

testChord2('Gm1','Gm', Gm);
```

Can someone steer me back onto the path of salvation?

Thanks in advance,

Paul

Comment: Can you specify which function you are trying to call and with what parameters and where in the code you are having trouble?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish. You have unreachable code (code written after return statements).

Comment: @HeatherSawatsky: Thanks for the sanity check! It's the little things that you overlook when you think you're chasing after bigger game (or something like that). I applied some basic changes and got it working perfectly. https://jsfiddle.net/8wr2e1k3/1/

Comment: Not really little things....

Comment: @Mikes3ds: Agreed! That was actually intended to be slightly sarcastic...